# Error using Matlab HDL Coder

Tags: matlab, vhdl, simulink, hdl, hdl-coder

I am trying to covert a matlab code into VHDL using HDL Coder. When I try to simulate my model it gives me the error :

```
Illegal Fixed-Point Data Type: the numbers of bits exceeded the supported maximum
```

I have used fixed data type in my blocks. Does any one know how I can remove this error please. It would be great help

Comment: Based on the error can you reduce the wordlength of the fixed-point types?

Comment: @Navan. I am already using very small length and have to keep the precision of my data.

Comment: Did you verify that your HDL Coder is configured correctly? How many bits does the the hardware you intend to use support? How many bit do you attempt to use?

Comment: @Daniel will check the number of bits supported by the hardware and also check the configuration.